# content does not appear in datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, wpfdatagrid

Well, I have a data class with some data objects like this:

```
    private ObservableCollection<bool> check = new ObservableCollection<bool>();
    public ObservableCollection<bool> Check
    {
        get { return check; }
        set
        {
            check = value;
            Notify("check");
        }
    }

    private ObservableCollection<string> user = new ObservableCollection<string>();
    public ObservableCollection<string> User
    {
        get { return user; }
        set
        {
            user = value;
            Notify("user");
        }
    }
```

And in the MainWindow I added a DataGrid like this:

```
    <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
      Name="dataGrid1" 
      CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserSortColumns="False" CanUserResizeColumns="True" CanUserReorderColumns="False" 
      ItemsSource="{Binding}">
        <DataGrid.Columns >
            <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header = "" Binding="{Binding Check, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" MinWidth="50" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header = "User" Binding="{Binding User, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" MinWidth="50" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

For the whole Window the datakontext ist set to the data class. In the constructor I called "DataContext = theData";  I added some values in the constructor of the data class and proofed by running the program the instance of this class. The values are correct added to the ObservableCollection.

But the values are not shown in the datagrid. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ItemsSource property of the DataGrid should be set or bound to an `IEnumerable<T>`. And a single column in the DataGrid should be bound to a property of the type `T`. You are trying to bind a DataGridTextColumn to an `ObservableCollection<string>` and a DataGridCheckBoxColumn to an `ObservableCollection<bool>` and this makes no sense. They should be bound to a `string` and `bool` property respectively. Please refer to the following sample code.

**Model:**

```
public class YourDataObject : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private bool _check;
    public bool Check
    {
        get { return _check; }
        set { _check = value; NotifyPropertyChanged(); }
    }

    private string _user;
    public string User
    {
        get { return _user; }
        set { _user = value; NotifyPropertyChanged(); }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

**View Model:**

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public ViewModel()
    {
        TheDataObjects = new ObservableCollection<YourDataObject>();
        TheDataObjects.Add(new YourDataObject());
        TheDataObjects.Add(new YourDataObject());
        TheDataObjects.Add(new YourDataObject());
    }
    public ObservableCollection<YourDataObject> TheDataObjects { get; private set; }
}
```

**View:**

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    DataContext = new ViewModel();
}
```

---

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
  Name="dataGrid1" 
  CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserSortColumns="False" CanUserResizeColumns="True" CanUserReorderColumns="False" 
  ItemsSource="{Binding TheDataObjects}">
    <DataGrid.Columns >
        <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header = "" Binding="{Binding Check, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" MinWidth="50" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header = "User" Binding="{Binding User, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" MinWidth="50" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: well, I wrote a new YourDataObject calss an implemented the Veiw Model in my existing data class beside some other data. it's a little bit different, but so I learned more about how it works and I'm happy!

Answer (score 0):

Try setting,

```
this.DataContext = theData;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set proper property to ItemsSource.

```
 ItemsSource="{Binding User}"
```

Above line will clear the issue. 
Also, you should Notify public properties in Setter.

```
Notify("Check");
Notify("User");
```

Comment: well, I think I have to notify the private properties in setter. My example was working fine for textboxes, and now I need a second dimension.